# Difficulty accessing and working with Django models/QuerySets

Tags: python, html, django

My goal is to pull ship data once I pick the ship number but I have no idea how.
Here is my model setup

```
    from django.db import models
    from django.contrib.auth.models import User
    
    
    class Hull (models.Model):
        hull = models.CharField(max_length = 33, )
    
        def __str__(self):
            return self.hull
    
    class Hull_Spec(models.Model):
        ship = models.ForeignKey(Hull, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        speed = models.FloatField()
        depth = models.FloatField()
        remarks  = models.CharField(max_length =300)
    
        def __many_fields_simple_array__(self):
            return [self.remarks, self.depth, self.speed]
```

Here is what I try

starting data

```
hull = SS1
depth = 10
speed = 10
remarks = 'remarks'
```

```
    from main.models import Hull. Hull_Spec
    hull = Hull.objects.get(hull = 'SS2')
    specs = hull.hull_spec_set.all()
    #which returns
    <QuerySet [<Hull_Spec: Hull_Spec object (2)>]>
```

This is where I get stuck. I can get all of the information if I use the id but I have no idea how to retrieve a spec list's id unless I retrieve it from the terminal as shown above. Is there another way I can retrieve the data from the queryset without having to use get(id =) since I know already which ship this spec data corresponds to already?

Comment: The relationship between the two models, is it 1:m ?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what that means?

Comment: One to many relationship?